# Debugging elastic search code with IntelliJ

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to debug the Elasticsearch source code with IntelliJ. I built the source with IntelliJ and the current Program argument is start. I tried passing the parameters necessary to create an index in the program argument section but it doesn't seem to work. Where do I need to pass the parameters to create indices or perform other operations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To being testing/debugging requests, you will need to start the server by adding the start command as a Program argument. Once the server has started, open up a terminal and provide curl commands. You can place break points in the code to view the workflows involved.